# Create turtles ONCE at setup and not in every tick

Tags: netlogo, agent

In my program, the turtle breed CO2s has initial concentration of 10, and the turtle breed glucose will start with 10 and increase by 10 each tick (as stated in the setup-feed procedure). The to go procedure includes a turtle breed bacteria that eats CO2s and glucose each tick. The problem is that with my current code both breed of turtles, CO2s and glucose, increase each tick. My current output Excel looks like this:

[image]

I hope my output Excel can look like this:

[image]

Any comments or suggestions on this issue?

```
Breed [glucose a-glucose];; Glucose
Breed [CO2s CO2]
Breed [bacteria bacterium]

 glucose-own [glucose_mass] 
 bacteria-own [bacteria_mass]
 CO2s-own [CO2s_mass]

Globals
[
time

Initial_concentration_glucose
Initial_concentration_CO2s
total_glucose
total_CO2s
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set time 0
  set Initial_concentration_glucose 0 
  set Initial_concentration_CO2s 0
  set total_glucose 0
  set total_CO2s 0

;;; BACTERIA;;;
  set-default-shape bacteria "default"
  create-bacteria (20)
  [ set color cyan
   set bacteria_mass 20 / 20
  ]
 ;;; CO2s;;;
  set-default-shape CO2s "circle"
  create-CO2s (10)
  [set color orange
   set CO2s_mass (10 / 10)
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   ]

  setup-feed
  output-1
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-feed

  set-default-shape glucose "circle";; Glucose shape
  Create-glucose (10) 
  [
   set glucose_mass 10 / 10
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

end

to output-1
if (file-exists? "TestINOUT-AD.csv") [carefully [file-delete "TestINOUT-AD.csv"] [print error-message]]
   file-open "TestINOUT-AD.csv"
      file-type "tick,"
      file-type "Initial_concentration_glucose,"
      file-type "Initial_concentration_CO2s,"
      file-type "Bacteria,"
      file-type "CO2s,"
      file-print "glucose,"
   file-close
end
```

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;; PROCEDURES
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

```
to go
   if not any? turtles [stop]

  Calculate_concentrations

  ask bacteria
   [ eat
  ]

  set time time + 1

  count_glucose
  count_CO2s

  output-2

 tick

if (time = 72) [stop]

end
```

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;HELPER PROCEDURES

```
to Calculate_concentrations
  set Initial_concentration_glucose (Initial_concentration_glucose + sum [glucose_mass] of glucose + 0.0000001)
   set Initial_concentration_CO2s (Initial_concentration_CO2s + sum [CO2s_mass] of CO2s + 0.0000001)
end

to eat
  let prey one-of glucose-here
  if prey != nobody
  [ask prey [die]]

   let prey2 one-of CO2s-here
  if prey2 != nobody
  [ask prey2 [die]]

end


to output-2
  file-open "TestINOUT-AD.csv"
   file-type ticks file-type ","
   file-type Initial_concentration_glucose file-type ","
   file-type Initial_concentration_CO2s file-type ","
  file-type total_CO2s file-type ","
   file-print total_glucose 
  file-close
end

to count_glucose
  set total_glucose (total_glucose + sum [glucose_mass] of glucose)
end

 to count_CO2s
    set total_CO2s (total_CO2s + sum [CO2s_mass] of CO2s )
end
```

Comment: your bacteria aren't actually eating any glucose or CO2 because they are only allowed to find prey on the same patch as them

Comment: Jen has correctly pointed out that you don't actually have *any* CO2s or Glucoses being created after setup, but instead that you are simply adding the total amounts from the current tick to those from the previous tick. For example, after one tick `total_glucose` has been set to 10. Then, you update it the next tick using `total_glucose + sum [glucose_mass] of glucose`. So: 10 + 10 is 20. So, now `total_glucose` is 20. Next tick, the process repeats, so it becomes 20 + 10, and so on. Since your bacteria never eat unless a food item spawns on them, your excel file is as you see.

Comment: Perhaps you just want `file-print sum [ glucose_mass ] of glucose`? Additionally, you create a column for "Bacteria" in `output-1`, but do not count them in `output-2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turtles are not being created, your procedure count_glucose is a cumulative sum of glucose_mass and this is what is being output in your file. But your question suggests that you think this is reporting the number of glucose agents.

```
to count_glucose
  set total_glucose (total_glucose + sum [glucose_mass] of glucose)
end
```

If you actually want to count the glucose agents, then you want `count glucose`

```
file-print count glucose
```

instead of:

```
file-print total_glucose
```

Comment: Thanks for you comments JenB. Sorry, I forgot to explain that I am trying to count the total mass of the CO2s and glucose at the beggining and at the end of each tick. For example, for CO2s 10 agents are created with a mass of (10 / 10) = 1. Thus the mass at the beggining is 10. But, if I created 5 CO2s with 2 of CO2s_mass, I will still get need to report the 10 of CO2s_mass, not the 5 CO2s. Then, after the bacteria eats some CO2s the count is done again. So, if 1 CO2s was eaten, in the case of CO2s_mass =2, then the final count should be 8. All this works fine :) (see next comment)

Comment: The problem is that in the next tick, no more CO2s should be created while 10 glucose_mass should be created. Thus, in the next tick I would like to get glucose_mass = 20 (which is already ok), and CO2s = 8 but instead I get 18 CO2s because CO2s_mass increased by 10. Please let me know if I explained myself. Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: No, you aren't actually creating any further CO2s or mass. The only place you have a `create' statement is in setup. And you aren't making any new mass in the go procedure, you are simply totalling the existing mass again and adding it to your previous total. I suggest you get rid of all the code to generate output and simply have a few monitors on your interface until the model does what you want. You can worry about report format after the model works.